# Changing type on element is not possible twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm relying on another plugins javascript that has code for a specific submit event that submits the form after some validation.

I'm not able to change that validation without hacking into that code.

Therefore I've came up with a hack without hacking into that plugin's code. 
I'm changing the input type from submit to button type so I can do my own validation without having to take in account for action that is triggered upon submit.

There are two radiobuttons with class `.give-gateway`. Basically I'm doing this.

**HTML** (element in form):

```
<input type="submit" class="give-submit give-btn" id="give-purchase-button" 
name="give-purchase" value="Donate Now" data-before-validation-label="Donate 
Now">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.give-gateway', check_gateway);

function check_gateway(id) {

        //Value from which radiobutton is selected
        if (current_gateway == 'swish') {
            alert('changing button from ORIGINAL to new. NOW IT SHOULD BE 
            TYPE BUTTON!!!'); 
            $('#give-purchase-button').prop('id', 'give-purchase-button- 
            new').prop('type','button');
            $('body').on('click touchend', '#give-purchase-button-new', function 
            (e) {
                alert('NEW give purchase button clicked');
                //some code...

            });

        }
        else {
            alert('changing button from NEW to original. NOW IT SHOULD BE TYPE 
            SUBMIT!!!');           
            $('#give-purchase-button-new').attr('id', 'give-purchase- 
            button').prop('type','submit'); 
        }
    }
```

This works the first time:

1. From Submit to button
2. From Button to Submit
3. From Submit to Button

**Step 3 (NOT WORKING (first click on swish gateway work but second time it does not change from submit to button)!? **Why?**)  **

*I've also tried to programmatically add onsubmit to form but the issue there is that other plugins jquery code has a listener for click event on the actual submit - button which means that that code are executed first anyway. I don't want that to happen.*

I've figured it out why now. When I click on another gateway the form is loaded with other content. When I go from swish to paypal. It loads content that is dependent of paypal stuff and creates a new submit - button. If I just change from type submit to button it does not affect anything because that change is made before the actual content is loaded (through ajax) and therefore creates a new submit button.

Comment: For your help, we need someone from Mars. You are already the best of this world :)

Comment: How are you changing the variable type? I don't see the type assignment code. Also, just a friendly reminder that running `$('body').on('click touchend'...)` will permanently bind that event to the selector result, so maybe run it outside the function, to bind the event only once.

Comment: $('#give-purchase-button-new').attr('id', 'give-purchase- 
            button').prop('type','submit');  changes the type.

Comment: Maybe first use type button on the html and after the click change it to submit in order to submit?

Comment: @A.Meshu - I have no influence of the elements original state.

Comment: Please note that some browsers don't allow changing the type of an input. Are you sure you really need to do this? Maybe you could just create two buttons, and hide/show them as appropriate.

Comment: @Barmar - I've been thinking that as well. No, I'm not sure. That might be a better solution :-)

Comment: Another option is to just set a global variable that controls what clicking on the button does.

Comment: @Barmar - I'm not sure that would work in this case, because I'm depending on another author's code. Maybe I'm not sure what you mean to 100%.

Comment: I missed that part of the question. It does complicate things.